# Simple email validation

Tags: java, regex, email-validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Verify email in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153716/verify-email-in-java)

I'm trying to do a very simple email validation. But the problem is when I try something like `tom@@@@gmail.com` it returns true.

Here are the codes:

```
public static boolean validateEmail(String email){
        boolean isValidEmail = false;
       // Input the string for validation
       // String email = "xyz@.com";
       // Set the email pattern string
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+");

       // Match the given string with the pattern
       Matcher m = p.matcher(email);

       // check whether match is found
       boolean matchFound = m.matches();

       StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(email, ".");
       String lastToken = null;
       while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
          lastToken = st.nextToken();
       }

       if (matchFound && lastToken.length() >= 2
          && email.length() - 1 != lastToken.length()) {


          // validate the country code
          isValidEmail = true;
       }
       else isValidEmail = false;

    return isValidEmail;
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

`.+@.+` will match anything, including `@`, followed by `@`, followed by anything, including `@`. Use `[^@]+@[^@]+` instead.

Or cease from reinventing the wheel, grab Apache Commons and use its [`EmailValidator`](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html).

Comment: How am I gonna use Apache Commons? Its the first time I heard about it.

Comment: @ChickenBoy: http://commons.apache.org/. It's a pretty nice library.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the class [`javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress`](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html) from the Javamail API (there is a `validate` method)

Comment: How am I gonna import that? I tried but its not in my default java library. Im so new to this. Please help.

Comment: It is in the Java EE distribution.

Comment: @ChickenBoy you can download this library on Oracle's website. Just look for "javamail". If you use maven, you can add the dependency on your pom.xml directly (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.4.4).

Answer (score 2):

This is a solved problem in numerous libraries. Do not reimplement your own.

Getting this 100% correct in regexps is much, much harder than you think it is.

Answer (score 2):

[This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) suggests that the following pattern matches [RFC 5322](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt) and covers most email addresses used today:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

It worked for a few quick tests that I made.

Consider storing the compiled pattern in a constant for improved performance.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+@{1}+\\.[a-z]+");`

**BUT:**

This my answer above is wrong exactly like the answer @larsmans, because:

*this(comment)me@demo.com* is a valid email.

You have to read the RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322

In fact, use a good library, as apache-commons.

Comment: An application validating an e-mail address does not have the obligation to validate all variations on e-mail address formats just because they are permitted in an Internet message. Also, if the address will be used for sending e-mail with SMTP, bear in mind that the e-mail address format permitted by SMTP is much more restricted and does not include comments (or for that matter, anything but the mailbox name, at sign, and FQDN).

Comment: Where do you get these information? Is there another RFC?

Comment: SMTP has gone through a number of revisions. RFC 821 is the latest which has been designated a standard. The latest *draft* standard for SMTP is RFC 5321.