# How do I identify the fake or incorrect email address?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Verify email in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153716/verify-email-in-java)

How do I identify the fake or incorrect email address

For example :  The  recipient’s correct email address is john.canada@maseke.com.  But when he submitted the form in the application, he entered an incorrect email address like john.canad@maseke.com . In this case, system should send an email to administrator stating that “since john.canad@maseke.com  is incorrect email address, en email is not delivered “ .

Web application (Java)

How do we implement the above requirement in Java.

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to send an email with a validation link or code inside.